# integrate red5 (red5-server-1.0.9-RELEASE) and Tomcat (tomcat8)

Tags: red5

When I integrate red5 (red5-server-1.0.9-RELEASE) and Tomcat (tomcat8), I copy the configuration file, and the following questions arise. Who can help me, thanks?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHQGf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBxC6.png)

```html
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'default.context' defined in URL [file:/F:/apache-tomcat-8.0.45/webapps/red5/WEB-INF/classes/beanRefContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.red5.server.Context@586d7ec1] with key 'global.context'; nested exception is javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: org.red5.server.jmx.mxbeans.ContextMXBean: Method org.red5.server.jmx.mxbeans.ContextMXBean.getResource has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
 at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:383)
 ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldish thread, but added this answer just in case someone needs.

What I think you are trying to do is install red5 into a vanilla tomcat 8.x install, but you need to build the red5 sever first using maven.

As the instructions state (https://github.com/Red5/red5-server) you need to build the server using these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Red5/red5-server.git
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package -P assemble
```

The archive file has everything you need, the red5 scripts, conf and libs directories are all there!

Just copy the contents of the zip (or tar) into the baseline tomcat 8.x directory. (the zip will be located in the target directory)

Then simply run the red5.bat/sh file and you are good to go.

Hope this help you or someone.

Comment: My mistake, the zip file created will run red5 standalone, you do not need to copy the contents of the files into a baseline tomcat. This was my first time setting up red5 like this. There may be some advantages, but you do not need to!